# Get metadata of all files in the media in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I need to retrieve metadata of files that are not images such as word, excel or pdf documents. I was able to retrieve the metadata when it was attached to a page or post but when its not attached, not getting anything.

I tried using `get_post_meta( $post_id );` and `wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );`

I'm only getting the following information when using `get_post_meta( $post_id );`:

```
Array
(
    [_wp_attached_file] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015/03/test.xlsx
        )

    [_edit_lock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1425404399:741
        )
)
```

Nothing for `wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the attachments (regardless of whether the are attached to a post or page) with:

```
$attachments = get_posts( array('post_type' => 'attachment) );
```

Make an array of the mime types you do not want:

```
$exclude = array(
    'image/jpeg',
    ...
);
```

Then you can go through them looking at the mime type:

```
foreach ($attachments as $attach) {
    if (!in_array($attach->post_mime_type, $exclude) {
    // Do what you want to do with it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wp_get_attachment_metadata doesn't seem to return metadata for files other than images (and videos I guess). Still you are able to insert description and alternative text for e.g. PDF files in media uploader. I am assuming you are referring to those fields.

Wordpress stores those values to post_content and post_excerpt so if you know the attachment id (post id) of your attachment then you can just query that post and print metadata:

```
$pdf = get_post($attachment_id);

echo $pdf->post_content;
echo $pdf->post_excerpt;
```